# Comunicación entre componentes estados

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-router-dom, react-navigation

Necesito comunicarme entre componentes; me explico: tengo la clase UploadFile y necesito acceder al nombre del archivo seleccionado que se ha guardado en el State desde la clase Register, es decir, a la variable documentName, son diferentes archivos y en la clase Register está importado el componente UploadFile.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import * as CONSTANTES from "../../constantes";
import CustomInput from "../components/customInput";
import Pressable from "react-native/Libraries/Components/Pressable/Pressable";



export default function UploadFile (props) {

  const [documentName, guardarNombreArchivo] = useState("");

  const pickDocumento = async (props) => {
    let result = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({});

  guardarNombreArchivo(result.name);
    //getDocumentUri( result.uri)
  };

  return (
    <View styles={styles.viewContainer}>
      <CustomInput
        value={documentName}
        //  onChangeText={props.getValue}
      />
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <Pressable
          style={styles.pressableStyle}
          //title="Seleccionar archivo"
         onPress={pickDocumento}
        >
          <Text>{'Seleccionar documento'}</Text>
        </Pressable>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};
```

```
export default function  Register  ({ navigation }, documentName)  {
  
  // console.log("Register => ", navigation);

  function formGetValues() {
    
        let objRegister = {
          dniNie: dniNie,
          archivo: documentName,
        };
    
        sendRegisterData(objRegister);
      }
```

Comment: Creo que tu solucion seria ocupar Redux, ayuda a comunicar estados entre componentes.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [React-native comunicación entre componentes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/504619/react-native-comunicaci%c3%b3n-entre-componentes)